# How to determine a control input so that an equilibrium point has $x_1 = 2$.

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

> Consider the nonlinear system: $$ \begin{align} \dot{x}_1 &= x_2 -
> x^2_1 \tag{1} \\ \dot{x}_2 &= -2x_1 - x_2 + x^3_1 + u \tag{2}
>  \end{align} $$ (a) Determine a constant external control $u^*$ so that
>   an equilibrium point has $x_1 = 2$.
>
> (b) Find all the equilibrium points of the system with $u=u^*$.
>
> (c) Determine a linearized model about each equilibrium point of the
>   system.
>
> (d) Determine which of these equilibrium points is locally stable.

For part(a), the equilibrium point(s) can be determined as follows:

$$ 
\begin{align} 
0 &= x_2 - x^2_1 \tag{3} \\ 
0 &= -2x_1 - x_2 + x^3_1 + u \tag{4}
\end{align} 
$$

From Eq(3), we get $x_2=x^2_1$ and substitute it in Eq(4), we get 
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= -2x_1 - x^2_1 + x^3_1 + u \\
0 &= x_1(-2 - x_1 + x^2_1) + u \\
0 &= x_1(x_1-2)(x_1+1) + u \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
For an equilibrium point to have $x_1=2$, the control $u$ must be zero in Eq(5). While the question doesn't restrict $u\neq 0$ but I feel the question requires a constant value other than the null. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: No. $u^*=0$ is the solution to (a).

Comment: @copper.hat  which (a)?

Comment: How many (a)s are there?

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I thought you meant a specific equation. So by this, I assume the only control input for part (a) is the zero input, right?

Comment: If $x_1 = 2$ then $x_2 = 4$ and $u$ must be zero, yes.